# PersistentActor который не смог

Tags: scala, akka

Разбираюсь с `Akka Persistence`.

*У меня есть небольшой **PersistentActor**:*

```
import akka.actor.ActorLogging
import akka.persistence.{PersistentActor, SnapshotOffer}

object Counter {
  sealed trait Operation {
    val count: Int
  }

  case class Increment(override val count: Int) extends Operation
  case class Decrement(override val count: Int) extends Operation

  case class Cmd(op: Operation)
  case class Evt(op: Operation)

  case class State(count: Int)

}

class Counter extends PersistentActor with ActorLogging {
  import Counter._
  println("Starting ...........................")


  var state: State = State(count = 0)
  def updateState(evt: Evt): Unit = evt match {
    case Evt(Increment(count)) =>
      state = State(count = state.count + count)
    case Evt(Decrement(count))  =>
      state = State(count = state.count - count)
  }

  // Persistent Identifier
  override def persistenceId = "counter-example"

  // Persistent receive on recovery mood
  override val receiveRecover: Receive = {
    case evt: Evt =>
      println(s"Counter receive ${evt} on recovering mood")
      updateState(evt)
    case SnapshotOffer(_, snapshot: State) =>
      println(s"Counter receive snapshot with data: ${snapshot} on recovering mood")
      state = snapshot
  }

  // Persistent receive on normal mood
  override val receiveCommand: Receive = {
    case cmd @ Cmd(op) =>
      println(s"Counter receive ${cmd}")
      persist(Evt(op)) { evt =>
        updateState(evt)
      }
    case something =>
      println(s"Counter got ${something}")
  }
}
```

Здесь я к нему обращаюсь:

```
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, Props}

object PersistentApp extends App {
  import Counter._

  val system = ActorSystem("persistent-actors")
  val counter = system.actorOf(Props[Counter])

  counter ! Cmd(Increment(3))
  counter ! Cmd(Increment(3))
  counter ! Cmd(Decrement(3))
  counter ! "print"

  Thread.sleep(100)
  system.terminate()
}
```

*Файлик **application.conf**:*

```
akka {
  persistence {
    journal {
      plugin = "akka.persistence.journal.leveldb"
      leveldb {
        dir = "journal"
        native = false
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Никак не могу понять в чем дело. Чтобы не делал получаю такой лог:

```
Starting ...........................
[WARN] [11/11/2018 17:05:55.748] [persistent-actors-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka.persistence.Persistence(akka://persistent-actors)] No default snapshot store configured! To configure a default snapshot-store plugin set the `akka.persistence.snapshot-store.plugin` key. For details see 'reference.conf'
[INFO] [11/11/2018 17:05:55.796] [persistent-actors-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://persistent-actors/user/$a] Message [section4AkkaPersistence.counter.Counter$Cmd] without sender to Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [11/11/2018 17:05:55.796] [persistent-actors-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://persistent-actors/user/$a] Message [section4AkkaPersistence.counter.Counter$Cmd] without sender to Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526] was not delivered. [2] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [11/11/2018 17:05:55.796] [persistent-actors-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://persistent-actors/user/$a] Message [section4AkkaPersistence.counter.Counter$Cmd] without sender to Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526] was not delivered. [3] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[INFO] [11/11/2018 17:05:55.796] [persistent-actors-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-8] [akka://persistent-actors/user/$a] Message [java.lang.String] without sender to Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526] was not delivered. [4] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://persistent-actors/user/$a#-2006795526]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
```

Судя по всему все сообщения летят мимо. Почему?

Comment: Надо либо убрать `  Thread.sleep(100)
  system.terminate()`, либо сделать `Thread.sleep()` больше по времени.

Comment: @avgolubev я пробовал

Comment: Ну у меня именно при таких изменениях всё работает на последней akka.